# iOS in-app purchase: Keeping consumable counter in keychain, do I need to document export compliance

Tags: ios, keychain

The answer to [iPhone - in-App purchase consumable correct approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449312/iphone-in-app-purchase-consumable-correct-approach) on stackoverflow is very appealing for keeping track of consumables in the keychain. However, using the keychain for this purpose (not username/password), will it trigger the need to document export compliance?

Comment: @patrix, regarding being "off-topic", I actually posted this on Stack Overflow first, but I considered it to be more appropriate here, as the question is not really about software development, but commercial/compliance implications of a technical solution.

Comment: Ah, on rereading the question I would agree :-) Thanks for getting back to me for this.

Answer (score 1):

The general consensus I've heard is no, it does not trigger export compliance. The OS is the one handling the encryption, not your app.